# Don't show one file ON DESKTOP

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I want to see all my hidden files except one file (not desktop.ini, it's a folder) on my dekstop, but how?

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick to make windows think it is an Operating system File, which will put it on an another Level of Hidden

open Command prompt, enter

```
attrib +s +h "C:\Users\{yourusername}\Desktop\{yourFolder}"
```

Change `+` to `-` to Show the folder again.

if you want to see it, Disable "Hide protected operating system files".

Edit: I found This on WikiHow, This is really cool! https://www.wikihow.com/Lock-a-Folder-Using-a-Batch-File, this will make hiding and unhiding your folder easy, Its not secure because the password is visible if you open the .bat with notpad. But cool nevertheless.